# Testing custom lock in Java

Tags: java

I have a MyLock class that implements the Lock interface. Now the constructor in MyLock accepts two Thread objects as parameters.

I am writing a test class for MyLock.

```
public class TestMyLock
{
    static MyLock mylck;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {           

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                mylck.lock();       //1 - gives error
                            //Critical code

                mylck.unlock();                 
            }

        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){

                mylck.lock();
                            //Critical code                 
                mylck.unlock();                 
            }

        });

        mylck = new MyLock(t1, t2);  //where to place this

        t1.start(); t2.start();

    }
}
```

Where is my test code going wrong. Basically, I need to test my MyLck functionality.

EDIT: The error -1 is because myLck is not initialized. It gives a compilation error. I would like to know how to initialize this, since to initialize, I need to pass the thread objects.

Comment: gives error: which one? and are you sure that is the correct code? (thread1 <-> t1)

Comment: Your code, exactly as written here, produces no compilation error for me.  Which compiler/IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be better to put mylck.lock() ... mylck.unlock() in a loop to make it run for longer time to detect flaws if this is feasible. We need to know how's MyLock.lock() is implemented to see what's the error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see what is wrong with this main class. The lock creation is done before threads are started, thus the mylck reference used in both run methods will not be null when call => it's ok.

On a side note, why do you implement your own lock ? The `java.util.concurrent.locks` package provides several common implementations.

Comment: I am trying to come up with a test code to verify my hw exercise, which is to write a lock.

Comment: Ok so I think your test code is ok. Off course in depends on the critical section lines and how you test that these line have really been "locked"